# c language strchr segmentation fault character replace

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, strchr

I need to replace every occurence of '&' to ',' in a C string.

I did this and it works

Code 1:

```
char *val, *querydup;
.
.
.
val=strchr(querydup,'&');
while(val != NULL) {
*val=',';
val=strchr(querydup,'&');
}
```

In order to be "elegant" I tried the following, but it leads to seg fault, to the point where even my pointer cursor gets corrupted!. weird, I'm running linux inside a vmware vm.

Code 2:

```
while(val=strchr(querydup,'&') != NULL) {
*val=',';
}
```

So what could be wrong?..

Do you consider code 1 to be "elegant"?...

Regards.

Comment: I suggest you put `val=strchr(querydup,'&')` in brackets inside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 6):

Your main issue [has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154309/c-language-strchr-segmentation-fault-character-replace/7154327#7154327) by [emboss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827060/emboss).

I'm answering the "elegance" part :)

You're checking the same characters over and over again.

Suppose `querydup` has `"&&&&&&&&&&"`. After the first few changes it has `",,,,,,&&&&"` and yet you still check from the beginning anyway.

Try re-using `val` for "elegance" :)

```
val = strchr(val, '&');
```

Comment: If you do this, you need to initialise `val` to `querydup`, so a `for()` loop is probably the most elegant: `for (val = querydup; val != NULL; val = strchr(val, '&'))`

Comment: @caf: assuming `querydup` can never be NULL, I prefer a `do {} while ()` and avoid a redundant test (equivalent to `querydup != NULL`). `val = querydup; do { val = strchr(val, '&'); if (val) *val++ = ','; } while (val); /* trust compiler to only test val once :) */`

Comment: @pmg: If you're going to go that way, then what about `val = querydup; while (val = strchr(val, '&'), val != NULL) *val = ',';`

Comment: That looks good too @caf. You left out the `++` to increase `val` past the new `','` :) Oh ... and I don't like the comma operator and cramming too much work inside the condition.

Comment: Personally I would just use the `for()` loop version - the overhead of a single additional test against `NULL` isn't worth worrying about, and in many cases the compiler will be able to elide it anyway.  I think you unfairly marginalise the comma operator though ;)

Comment: val=querydup;
    while((val=strchr(val,'&')) != NULL) {
     *val=',';
    }
and worked perfectly, the "for" version looks very good too, and I will use it on newer code.

Answer (score 4):

It's the [operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm), try

```
while((val=strchr(querydup,'&')) != NULL) {
    *val=',';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a simpler solution would be to actually do it manually:

```
char *ptr = querydup;
while (*ptr) {
    if (*ptr == '&') {
        *ptr = ',';
    }
    ptr++;
}
```

It's more lines of code, but it only goes through the string once, where the repeated executions of strchr() will go through the string multiple times.

Comment: Forgot to increment ptr the first time through!

Comment: Looks good, however pmg's solution seems even more "elegant" :) thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning val a boolean value. Your code is equivalent to:

```
while(val = (strchr(querydup,'&') != NULL))
```

Change it to:

```
while((val = strchr(querydup,'&')) != NULL)
```

Comment: The last one is not valid.  The `!=` has higher precedence than `=`, so the left hand side of the `=` operator is `NULL != val`, which is not an lvalue.